Generate Covariance for baysesian inference
I’m currently working on a project where I want to use Bayesian inference to derive the distribution of a set of parameters. I assume these parameters are somewhat correlated, and I would like to use Bayesian inference to also derive the covariance matrix for the multivariate normal distribution. However, I’m not entirely sure what the best way is to generate a positive definite covariance matrix from an array of numbers. I'm not currently not looking for a prior of the matrix.
My current approach is as follows:

I use the array of numbers to generate a triangular matrix $A$ by inserting the values of the array into the upper triangular part. For example, given the array $ (a_1, \dots, a_6)$, I construct the matrix:

$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
0 & a_4 & a_5 \\
0 & 0 & a_6
\end{pmatrix}
$ 
with $a_i > 0$.

I then generate a positive definite and symmetric matrix by computing $AA^T$, which I use as the covariance matrix.

However, in this approach, the values $a_i$ don’t have a clear interpretation, and I’m uncertain whether this method can generate all possible positive semi-definite covariance matrixes. Is there a better method I could use?
An alternative approach, with better interpretability, might involve first creating a diagonal matrix containing the variances of each parameter and a correlation matrix. For example, given the array $(a_1, \dots, a_6)$, I could construct the matrices:
$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_3
\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_4 & a_5 \\
a_4 & 1 & a_6 \\
a_5 & a_6 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$ 
with $ a_1, a_2, a_3 > 0$ and $|a_4|, |a_5|, |a_6| \leq 1 $.
The covariance matrix would then be given by $ABA$. However, this matrix is not necessarily positive definite. How can I ensure that the resulting matrix is positive definite?

Not an answer. But perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my Bayesian tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65
